# Use crypto module in react-native on windows

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, react-native, browserify

In my current react-native app, I have a dependency that uses "crypto" module.

It appears that on Mac, everything runs fine. But on Windows, I get a requiring unknown module "crypto".

I tried using rn-nodeify but it doesn't seem to help.

Comment: `npm install crypto`?

Comment: @MaxwellLasky I wish it is that simple =(

Comment: what version of NodeJS do you have installed on Mac, and what version on Windows? This sound suspiciously like an older version got installed on Windows.

Comment: I have a similar question [*Howto patch/shim crypto.getRandomValues for React Native*](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45301900/8295283), that - when answered - will also answer this question. **PS** Instead of `rn-nodeify` I use the cleaner method provided by [`ReactNativify`](https://github.com/philikon/ReactNativify).