# Howto patch/shim crypto.getRandomValues for React Native

Tags: node.js, react-native, browserify, browserify-shim, libsodium

I am porting some packages created for NodeJS to React Native using [ReactNativify](https://github.com/philikon/ReactNativify) to rewrite Node API object dependencies to their browserify equivalents.

One of them is `crypto`. In [`transformer.js`](https://github.com/philikon/ReactNativify/blob/master/transformer.js#L18) (or `.babelrc`) I have:

```
// The following plugin will rewrite imports. Reimplementations of node
// libraries such as `assert`, `buffer`, etc. will be picked up
// automatically by the React Native packager.  All other built-in node
// libraries get rewritten to their browserify counterpart.

[require('babel-plugin-rewrite-require'), {
  aliases: {
    crypto: 'crypto-browserify',
    // ...
  },
  throwForNonStringLiteral: true,
}],
```

In ReactNativify [`global.js`](https://github.com/philikon/ReactNativify/blob/master/global.js#L13) there is this code (which I excluded, because it is not meant for production):

```
// Don't do this in production. You're going to want to patch in
// https://github.com/mvayngrib/react-native-randombytes or similar.
global.crypto = {
  getRandomValues(byteArray) {
    for (let i = 0; i < byteArray.length; i++) {
      byteArray[i] = Math.floor(256 * Math.random());
    }
  },
};
```

.

> **My first question**: How is `getRandomValues` correctly patched for production?

---

There is a second option, and that is using [`react-native-crypto`](https://github.com/mvayngrib/react-native-crypto) (a clone of `crypto-browserify`)

Ideally I should just be able to do this in `transformer.js`:

```
  aliases: {
    crypto: 'react-native-crypto', // instead of 'crypto-browserify'
    // ...
  },
```

But `react-native-crypto` uses [rn-nodeify](https://github.com/mvayngrib/rn-nodeify) instead of ReactNativify, which generates a `shim.js` to be imported in `index.android.js` / `index.ios.js` with code similar to this:

```
if (require('./package.json').dependencies['react-native-crypto']) {
    const algos = require('browserify-sign/algos')
    if (!algos.sha256) {
        algos.sha256 = {
        "sign": "ecdsa",
        "hash": "sha256",
        "id": new Buffer("")
        }
    }

    if (typeof window === 'object') {
        const wCrypto = window.crypto = window.crypto || {}
        wCrypto.getRandomValues = wCrypto.getRandomValues || getRandomValues
    }

    const crypto = require('crypto')
    const randomBytes = crypto.randomBytes
    crypto.randomBytes = function (size, cb) {
        if (cb) return randomBytes.apply(crypto, arguments)

        const arr = new Buffer(size)
        getRandomValues(arr)
        return arr
    }

    crypto.getRandomValues = crypto.getRandomValues || getRandomValues

    function getRandomValues (arr) {
        // console.warn('WARNING: generating insecure psuedorandom number')
        for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        arr[i] = Math.random() * 256 | 0
        }

        return arr
    }
}
```

I don't know if all this shim code is needed when using ReactNativify, and couldn't find good sources, so ...

> **My second question**: How to use `react-native-crypto` in 'the proper ReactNativify way'?

---

I've created github issues in ReactNativify and react-native-crypto repo's:

- [Howto use getRandomValues in production?](https://github.com/philikon/ReactNativify/issues/10)
- [Using ReactNativify instead of rn-nodeify?](https://github.com/mvayngrib/react-native-crypto/issues/16)

Versions:

```
node               7.10.1       /usr/local/bin/node  
npm                4.2.0        /usr/local/bin/npm   
yarn               0.24.6       /usr/bin/yarn        
react-native-cli   2.0.1       
app rn version     0.45.1      
ignite             2.0.0        /usr/local/bin/ignite
```

Comment: **Note**: Shimming was not viable, now looking into [Viable options for running NodeJS on Android (Aug 2017)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45649995/8295283)